# What's the fastest database that I can put on a server and access from several computers?

Tags: mysql, berkeley-db

I don't require SQL or any other high level language. I can access it from C.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a noSQL option like [Redis](http://redis.io/) would be something to look into.  It's [fast](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks), [persistant](http://redis.io/topics/persistence), and has a [C (and others) API](http://redis.io/clients).

Comment: I need the ability to search based on the values of the keys. It looks like Redis cannot do that :(

Comment: Well, suppose I have 1000 key-value pairs, and 22 of them have a value of "fubar", but there are 10000000 possible values. Are you saying that after I insert each pair I should also create a set for all pairs that have the value "fubar"? If so I'd need 10000000 such sets to cover all possible values.

Comment: Yes, I don't believe Redis allows duplicate keys for sets, so you'd have to make the setname for each key name you wanted (at least that's my understanding, I haven't had the chance to really use Redis for more than messing around with it).  :-(

Comment: Redis seems like a near-miss. It's got most of what I need but not this key feature. Oh well.

Comment: I noticed that you tagged this with "Berkeley DB". That would be my first reply. Berkeley DB is exactly the product that you'd want given the high level description that you provided. You can find a link to BDB here: http://bit.ly/hwYyw9.